# Spark Streaming UpdateStateByKey

Tags: spark-streaming

I am running a spark streaming 24X7 and using updateStateByKey function to save the computed historical data like in the case of NetworkWordCount Example..

I am tried to stream a file with 3lac records with 1 sec sleep for every 1500 records.
I am using 3 workers

1. Over a period updateStateByKey is growing, then the program throws the following exception

ERROR Executor: Exception in task ID 1635
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

```
14/10/23 21:20:43 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 29170.0:2 failed 1 times; aborting job
14/10/23 21:20:43 ERROR DiskBlockManager: Exception while deleting local spark dir: /var/folders/3j/9hjkw0890sx_qg9yvzlvg64cf5626b/T/spark-local-20141023204346-b232
java.io.IOException: Failed to delete: /var/folders/3j/9hjkw0890sx_qg9yvzlvg64cf5626b/T/spark-local-20141023204346-b232/24

14/10/23 21:20:43 ERROR Executor: Exception in task ID 8037
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/folders/3j/9hjkw0890sx_qg9yvzlvg64cf5626b/T/spark-local-20141023204346-b232/22/shuffle_81_0_1 (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
```

How to handle this?
I guess updateStateByKey should be periodically reset as its growing in a rapid rate, please share some example on when and how to reset the updateStateByKey.. or i there any other problem? shed some light.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the CheckPoint
ssc.checkpoint("path to checkpoint")